# Java 17, Spring boot test, @Sql script exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-test, hikaricp

After upgrade to `java 17`, `spring boot 2.5.5` I cannot use `@Sql` script

This is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = {App.class})
@ContextConfiguration(loader = CustomContextLoaderProvider.CustomContextLoader.class)
@SuppressWarnings("Duplicates")
@Sql(scripts = "/clear_data.sql", executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
public class ApiControllerTest {...}
```

And context loader provider for postgres test containers

```
public class CustomContextLoaderProvider {

  private static final PostgreSQLContainer postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:10.5");

  static {
    postgres.start();
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(postgres::stop));
 }

  public static class CustomContextLoader extends SpringBootContextLoader {

    @Override
    protected String[] getInlinedProperties(MergedContextConfiguration config) {
      return ArrayUtils.addAll(
          super.getInlinedProperties(config),
          "spring.datasource.url=" + postgres.getJdbcUrl(),
          "spring.datasource.username=" + postgres.getUsername(),
          "spring.datasource.password=" + postgres.getPassword());
    }
  }
}
```

**stacktrace**:

```
  Failed to execute SQL scripts for test context [DefaultTestContext@19553973 testClass = ApiControllerTest, testInstance = ApiControllerTest@9af804b, testMethod = delete@ApiControllerTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@7bb6ab3a testClass = ApiControllerTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class App}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{test}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@2bec854f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@2a7ed1f, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@5f0fd5a0, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@4fa1c212, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@1cb346ea, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@6f204a1a], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'CustomContextLoaderProvider$CustomContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.populatedRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.resetRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]: the configured DataSource [jdk.proxy3.$Proxy138] (named '') is not the one associated with transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] (named '').
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute SQL scripts for test context [DefaultTestContext@19553973 testClass = ApiControllerTest, testInstance = ApiControllerTest@9af804b, testMethod = delete@ApiControllerTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@7bb6ab3a testClass = ApiControllerTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class App}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{test}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@2bec854f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@2a7ed1f, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@5f0fd5a0, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@4fa1c212, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@1cb346ea, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@6f204a1a], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'CustomContextLoaderProvider$CustomContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.populatedRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.resetRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]: the configured DataSource [jdk.proxy3.$Proxy138] (named '') is not the one associated with transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] (named '').
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:263)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.lambda$executeSqlScripts$0(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:201)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:201)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:148)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:445)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
```

this exception throws here (`SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener`):

```
if (dataSource != null && dataSourceFromTxMgr != null && !sameDataSource(dataSource, dataSourceFromTxMgr)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Failed to execute SQL scripts for test context %s: " +
                    "the configured DataSource [%s] (named '%s') is not the one associated with " +
                    "transaction manager [%s] (named '%s').", testContext, dataSource.getClass().getName(),
                    dsName, txMgr.getClass().getName(), tmName));
        }
```

`dataSource` and  `dataSourceFromTxMgr`, are equals, but they are both proxies, so when `.equals` method is invoked, it compare real object with proxy(which of course returns `false`)

I try to debug this exception and found the cause.
The problem can be in `JpaTransactionManager`. For some reason `dataSource` is `proxy object` whereas in old version `datasource` was real `hikari datasource`. I am not sure that is it a real problem and I have no ideas how to fix it

Comment: Spring Boot won't create a proxy for your `DataSource` by default so it must be something in your app that you haven't shared thus far that's causing it to do so. Can you share a complete, minimal example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson it will be not very easy. But i change only versions for ```java```, ```spring boot``` and other dependencies. I am not changed code nor properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in javaMelody.
Java melody creates proxy for everything, so i excluded it spring boot autoconfiguration and it works

In the `application-test.properties` I added this:

`spring.autoconfigure.exclude=net.bull.javamelody.JavaMelodyAutoConfiguration`